# Is there a way to select which methods to use when running application in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, configuration, testng

I have a test suite (relies on TestNG, if that is of any importance) and I want to be able to choose which API methods to run, something like choosing a run configuration. Specifically, I have one set of create-put-post-get-methods that log all the API responses and another set that don't. Both of the sets are inside a API base class. If 98% of the time I want to use the first set of methods, but in a case that I would have to check for response messages, I would want to use the second set of methods, would there be a way to configure this in IntelliJ? If yes, how?

Comment: Do you mean to have some UI where you would segregate tests into groups?